# C# xmlserialization storing one class in two different way - possible?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

is it possible to use C# XmlSerialization API to store single class in two different ways ?
For example

```
class Test
{
     int group1_attr1;
     int group1_attr2;
     int group2_attr1;
}
```

I would like to have a way how to split class fields into two parts(groups - with specified attributes) and each time I call Serialize to control which part will be stored. For example if saving as group1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org  /2001/XMLSchema">
<group1_attr1>0</group1_attr1>
<group1_attr2>0</group1_attr2>
</Test>
```

if saving as group2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org  /2001/XMLSchema">
<group2_attr1>0</group2_attr1>
</Test>
```

Is there a way how to do it in a "clean" way ? If not in xmlserialization then in binary perhaps ?
Then I would like to know what is the best way how to merge those two files into single instance of Test. (Note that fields from group1 and group2 do not overlap)

Comment: Why don't you store these propertys in a List<T>/Dictionary<T> and refill that collection before serializing? You should consider redesigning if this is really an issue.

Comment: If you create interfaces describing you attribute groups in different interfaces, you would probably can sole this issue using interface driven XML serialization, (and, as a plus, interfaces supports multiple inheritance). Think about it. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code demonstrating how to serialize like you want, however, deserialization will be more tricky because it's not straightforward to deserialize into an existing instance (see [How to use XmlSerializer to deserialize into an existing instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531852/how-to-use-xmlserializer-to-deserialize-into-an-existing-instance)).

```
public class Test
{
  public int group1_attr1;
  public int group1_attr2;
  public int group2_attr1;
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes xa = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes();
     xa.XmlIgnore = true;
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides xo1 = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides();
     xo1.Add(typeof(Test), "group1_attr1", xa);
     xo1.Add(typeof(Test), "group1_attr2", xa);

     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides xo2 = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeOverrides();
     xo2.Add(typeof(Test), "group2_attr1", xa);

     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs1 = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Test), xo1);
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs2 = 
        new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Test), xo2);

     Test t1 = new Test();
     t1.group1_attr1 = 1;
     t1.group1_attr2 = 2;
     t1.group2_attr1 = 3;
     using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
     {
        xs1.Serialize(sw, t1);
        Console.WriteLine(sw);
     }

     using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
     {
        xs2.Serialize(sw, t1);
        Console.WriteLine(sw);
     }
  }
}
```

The deserialization could maybe merge the XML before deserializing:

```
     Test t2 = new Test();
     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs3 = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
     string mergedXml = MergeSerializedXml(group1, group2);

     using (System.IO.StringReader sr = new System.IO.StringReader(mergedXml))
     {
        t2 = (Test)xs3.Deserialize(sr);
     }
...

  static string MergeSerializedXml(string x1, string x2)
  {
     System.Xml.XmlDocument xd = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
     xd.LoadXml(x1);
     System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings xrs = new System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings();
     xrs.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
     using (System.Xml.XmlReader xr = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(x2), xrs))
     {
        while (xr.Read() && !xr.IsStartElement())
           ;
        xr.MoveToContent();
        xr.Read();
        System.Xml.XmlNode xn = xd.ChildNodes[1];
        do
        {
           xn.AppendChild(xd.ReadNode(xr));
        } while (xr.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EndElement);
     }
     return xd.OuterXml;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, XmlAttributeOverrides was something I tried prior to asking here however I overlooked the  xa.XmlIgnore = true;
option - thanks for pointing that out. Now it seems to be working. As of merging it - what you suggest was exactly my idea as well as I couldn't find any support for it in the API. From your reply I deduce that there indeed does not exist anything in the serialization API to support merging and hence the XML merging is the best approach. Many thanks again ! (the source code is much more than I asked)

Comment: @Peter - Notice that you can accept this as your preferred answer, which will mark the question as answered (and give me some points, another form of thanks) if you do in fact consider the question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Composition will sort of allow you to do this, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance. If you serialize `CompositeGroup1` then stick it in an instance of `CompositeData`. Do the same for `CompositeGroup2`. There's no way to do what you are asking for, as you asked it, with the built in serializers. When you serialize data it will always generate the full serialization for that type.

```
class CompositeData
{
  public CompositeGroup1 Group1 { get; set; }
  public CompositeGroup2 Group2 { get; set; }
}

class CompositeGroup1
{
  public int Attr1 { get; set; }
  public int Attr2 { get; set; }
}

class CompositeGroup2
{
  public int Attr1 { get; set; }
}
```

You could also consider making `CompositeData` implement abstract classes, one for each grouping. You can use some other JSON serializers that use the type passed in instead of the runtime type to generate the serialized data.

```
var json1 = serializer.Serialize<AbstractGroup1>(new CompositeData());
var json2 = serializer.Serialize<AbstractGroup2>(new CompositeData());
```

However, putting them back together again would still be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can loook into my project, [Xml Serialization Framework](http://xmlserialization.codeplex.com), that will use interfaces idiom to solve the same issue as you might have

Example:

To serialize class instance/object

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

you would probably declare interfaces to use in metadata driven xml runtime serialization:

```
interface IPersonRoot
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRootSerializer("Body")]
interface IPersonCustomRoot
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

interface IPersonCustomAttribute
{
    [XmlAttributeRuntimeSerializer("Id")]
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This framework supports even working with partial update of living instances using particular interfaces/XML formats:

to/from XML using IPersonRoot interface:

```
        <Person>
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
        </Person>
```

to/from XML using IPersonCustomRoot interface:

```
        <Body>
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
        </Body>
```

to/from XML using IPersonCustomAttribute interface:

```
        <Person Id="John Doe" />
```

Have a nice day,

Cheers ;)

Artur M.

Comment: And, of cause, less code - the better. You sholdn't spend hours on a such a simple task, I already took care about this issues, having build interface driven XML serialization framework ;)